# Is it more efficient to set more restrictive collations in MySQL columns that do not require utf8 characters?

Tags: mysql, indexing, unicode, collation

Creating a new table where I want a few `VARCHAR` columns to be indexed, but only one of them really needs `utf8_unicode_ci` collation.

Would it be any more efficient when searching the table to only set that single column to `utf8_unicode_ci` collation?

Or is it the same if I collate the entire table with `utf8_unicode_ci` collation?

Comment: no, have you tried FULL TEXT INDEXING

Comment: Do what is appropriate; don't worry about efficiency.  Also, `utf8_unicode_ci` is very old.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a *binary* collation, string comparisons are a little bit faster.

When you use a collation like utf8_unicode_ci, MySQL must do string comparisons character by character, so it can tell if each character is equivalent according to the rules in the collation you use.

But with a binary collation, MySQL is optimized to use the system call `memcmp()` to compare the whole string as literal bytes. This means there are no character equivalency rules. This comparison is case-sensitive.

However, the performance advantage of this is minor, and it's much more of an advantage to use an index.